# react js place the picture at the top of the window along the width of the window

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to place a gif file at the top of the screen, but I didn't succeed. so far, I have made it so that the gif file is placed on the entire page..:

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(https://media.tenor.com/kKmvIr30vQYAAAAj/stars-changing-colors.gif)',position: 'absolute', height:'100', width:'100',
bottom: 0, top:0,left:0, right:0, backgroundSize:'cover'}}>
```

[image]

tell me pls, how should i make it, as I depicted in the picture?

Answer (score 2):

Try giving it a height(instead of `bottom`)

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(https://media.tenor.com/kKmvIr30vQYAAAAj/stars-changing-colors.gif)',position: 'absolute', height:'100', width:'100', top:0,left:0, right:0, height: 100, backgroundSize:'cover'}}>
```